# Keyboard (mostly) doesn't work in Wine

Tags: keyboard, gentoo, wine

When I run any program in wine (e.g. notepad), I can use the keyboard
just fine until I click the mouse. As soon as I click the mouse for any
reason, the keyboard stops working entirely.

I'm using default X.Org settings, and adding `--without-xinput2` to Wine
has no effect. I am using a laptop, and plugging in an external USB
keyboard produces the same problem exactly.

There are never any error messages that seem to relate to the keyboard,
but this error message always shows up a few times. It doesn't look
important, but, just in case, here it is:

```
fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x30038/1400007 wait timed out
```

Here are some versions, in case any of this matters:

> **Wine:** 1.3.21
>   **Kernel:** 2.6.39 (Gentoo r1)
>   **X.Org X server:** 1.10.2
>   **Window manager:** musca (0.9.24)

Additionally, in some programs (e.g. StarCraft), the keyboard never
even starts working. In this case, text gets entered into another
program. For example, if I open it from the terminal, anything I type
will appear in the terminal after I quit. I think this might be a
separate issue, though, since that does not happen at all with notepad.

**Update:** I just noticed that 1.3.21 is a development version of Wine,
so I installed 1.2.3 instead. Disappointingly, the problem persists
exactly as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the window manager: musca is a tiling window manager
with a stacking mode, and flipping from tiling mode to stacking mode
resolves the issue completely.

It works even better in regular stacking window managers such as
fluxbox.